# Clean multiple JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

I was wondering about how to clean multiple JTextField in a Java applicatio, without setting the text with an empty string for each field.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do it differently? I guess you could do it by `getDocument().remove(0, length)` or by setting a fresh document model, but both alternatives are worse than `.setText("")`

If you want some "global" clear-button (similar to an HTML <input type=reset />) the answer is that it's **not possible** in Java. You have to store the components in a collection somehow, and loop them through and clear each component one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Track all the instances in an array? Swing does not majically know what's a JTextField and whats not.

And to my knowledge, setting the text to an empty string is the only way to clear text. T

Comment: A `Collection<>`. Actually, go straight for a model in Swing - `Collection<Document>`.